# Replace single quotes to double and vice versa in file by single command line

Tags: command-line, terminal

Are there ways to do it more clean/simple than this:

```
$ tr '"' '?' < f.txt > f1.txt && tr "'" '"' < f1.txt > f.txt \
    && tr '?' "'" < f.txt > f1.txt && rm f.txt && mv f1.txt f.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use longer sets in your `tr` command:

```
tr \'\" \"\' < f.txt > f1.txt && mv t1.txt f.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use sed with its `-i` (in-place) flag (requires GNU sed):

```
sed -i "y/'\"/\"'/" f.txt
```

The sed found on macOS needs an option for the `-i` flag; to overwrite the original file, you'd use `sed -i ''`.